# Trigger with compile errors

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't figure out why this trigger it is failing. I have a Oracle 11G database.
Error is: Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER application
BEFORE INSERT ON candidates
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE clubstate CHAR(1);
BEGIN
    SELECT open INTO clubstate FROM clubs WHERE club = :NEW.club;
    IF clubstate = 'C'
        THEN 
            :NEW.rej_date := SYSDATE;
    END IF;
END application;
/
```

My tables are

```
"CANDIDATES(nick, club, member*, type, req_date, req_msg, rej_date*, rej_msg*)"
"CLUBS (name, founder*, cre_date, end_date*, slogan, open)"
```

EDIT: I should say what I.m trying to do,

What I.m trying is when "INSERT" in candidates, the trigger checks if the club it's open or not. If the club it's closed, then it will set in rej_date the datetime of the rejection.

Comment: What are the compile errors?

Comment: Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors. :/

Comment: That says that there are errors.  In SQL Plus you should now type "SHOW ERRORS".  In other tools they are normally shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
FROM clubs WHERE club = :NEW.club
                 ^^^^
```

But your clubs table doesn't have a column called club

Comment: @Salmon54 You need to figure out how to see the compilation errors, it would have told you what line the error was on and what was wrong e.g. "3/22 PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "CLUB": invalid identifier

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know of "Show errors" command. It will help me :)!  Thank you